# Displaying custom local image marker in OSM using OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, angular, gis, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have followed the tutorial on how to display a custom image as a marker from this article: https://medium.com/attentive-ai/working-with-openlayers-4-part-3-setting-customised-markers-and-images-on-map-da3369a81941

However, when using my own local project structure to reference my png image, it does not get rendered on the map.

Here is my current code:

```js
var aPoint = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]))
var aFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: aPoint
})
var aFeatureStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    //src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Dot.png'
    src: '../../../dott.png'
  })
})
aFeature.setStyle(aFeatureStyle)
var aSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [aFeature]
})
var aLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: aSource
})



var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        }),
        aLayer
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
        zoom: 14
    })
})
```

When using the src: **'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Dot.png'** variant, the required dot gets displayed, but when using 
**src: '../../../dott.png'** no markers are displayed.

I have definitely specified the right path to my local png file, so I am out of ideas why this code doesn't work.

I am using the Angular framework and running this on a local development server using Node.

Comment: What does your browser's error console say?

Comment: There is no error in the browser console

Comment: When looking at the network tab in the dev tools, is the png loaded?

Comment: It says 404, but I am pretty sure the path to my png file is correct. I even used the full path and it still gives 404

Comment: I've found the cause of the problem. The local png file is trying to get accessed using the following URL in a HTTP GET request: http://localhost:4200/<full_local_path>/Dot.png, and this is clearly not referencing the internal project structure and so the png file cannot be found at that address. However, I still don't know how to ensure a referral to the local png file correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out, and I feel like I should've known this earlier, but since I'm new to Angular I didn't spot it straight away.

Any images that are needed to be referenced in source code in Angular need to be in **src/assets/images** folder in the Angular project structure. Then by specifying the path as **src: '../assets/images/Dot.png'** the image is successfully loaded with a 200 OK response, seen in the Network tab of a browser's Developer Tools.

Comment: However, it's not clear for me how to reference image by RELATIVE TO COMPONENT path if I want to make my OpenLayers component as a reusable library.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me, I solved it by using

```
import imagePath from '../../../dott.png'
```

and than using the `imagePath` variable instead using the path `../../../dott.png`

Comment: It gives me an error "module not found" if I do that